# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS Input audio sounds as a robotic gargle during videocalls skype, facebook and other services

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, facebook

So here's the scoop, I could send audios with no problem and hear everything fine when I play them back, but when I make video calls the recieving party cannot understand my audio. The audio is distorted and sounds like a robotic gargle. I've tryed various fixes but nothing seems to work. Mainly all the fixes related to audio here on the forum.

Comment: Hi. Could You update Your question with links to the solutions You tried?

Comment: Ok, let me give you a bit more detail. The thing is I need to take a video call interview using ZOOM. My mic and headphone weren't working so the first thing I did was to run "$ alsactl restore" this made my headphone and microphone jack start working.   

When I noticed the robotic gargle I lowered the input volume but that didn't seem to work. I have been messing around with pavucontrol but still no fix. @kcpr

Comment: Thanks for sharing more information. I would recommend editing Your question and pasting it there to make it easier to access by some new people interested in helping You solve this problem.  
Anyway, have You tried using downloadable Zoom client ( https://zoom.us/support/download ) or just some other web browser?